# Git - Merge between different versions

Tags: git

Good afternoon everyone,
this is my first topic.

Next, the repository structure I have is:

- master
- 1.0.2 (branch)
- 1.0.3 (branch)
- 1.0.4 (branch)
- 1.0.5 (branch)

They were created as follows:

master = 1.0.2> new branch 1.0.2 from master> new branch 1.0.3 from master - update files> Merge branch 1.0.3 to master> new branch 1.0.4 from master - update files> Merge branch 1.0.4 to master> new branch 1.0.5 from master - update files> Merge branch 1.0.5 to master

That way it works perfectly for me.

However, I noticed that the 1.0.3 branch had some invalid files, so I decided to check it out, and update several files. After that, I committed and pushed. I didn't merge for the higher versions, because there were no problems with them, and all the files were correct.

Now, I needed to change 1 file in branch 1.0.3 and I need to replicate this fix to 1.0.4, 1.0.5 and master.

**Problem: When merging from branch 1.0.3 to branch 1.0.4, 811 changes are found, however I changed only 1 file.**

I need to tell git: "The merge between branch 1.0.3 and 1.0.4 has already been done, notice how the difference is, only the commits going forward. From now on I already made sure they are right." Just like when I merge from version 1.0.4 to version 1.0.5, only the file I changed is considered a change, although if you compare all files there are many other changes.

I hope it's clear,
if anyone has any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: If you have done it correctly, meaning with one or few commits on top of corresponding branch, you may simple cherry pick it (them) by running `git checkout 1.0.4; git cherry-pick -<$AMOUNT> 1.0.3`, where `<$AMOUNT>` is amount of commits from the top of 1.0.3 branch to cherry pick. It's possible you have to resolve conflicts. Same can be repeated with the rest. But even better flow is to **first** fix it in master, and **then** waterfall to the stable branches.

Comment: Short answer: You need `cherry-pick` and not `merge`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
As I understand it, I will have to perform the following steps:

1- In branch 1.0.3, copy the SHA from the last commit 745be43637fba (as I would like to track only new commits from here)
2- In branch 1.0.4, execute: "cherry-pick 745be43637fba"
3- When doing this, the following message was returned: "commit 745be43637fba is a merge, but no -m option was provided."

Recalling that both version 1.0.3 and 1.0.4 are branches, created from the "master".

any tips?
thanks